# Getting only the filename in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, path, filenames

When i have a variable like:

**$storagePath = ('/xampp/htdocs/systeembeheer/public/download');**

```
$files = File::allFiles($storagePath);

return View::make('documentatie.overzicht') ->with('files', $files);
```

In my view, the files displayed as:

`/xampp/htdocs/systeembeheer/public/download/test.txt`, but I want to see only `test.txt`.

Comment: Have you tried to do `echo basename($file);` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did: 
<a href="/filedownload/"><?php echo basename($file);?></a> in my view file and it works now!

Comment: No problem, i have wrote my solution as answer. Feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to use [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) which returns trailing name component of path.

So in your view use something like

```
//$file is full path 
echo basename($file);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works with larave 8 and php 8

Comment: @Ivandez, it works in every Laravel version, because it's plain PHP